# How to find greatest no.of 0s in a string in between 1s in java in traditional way

Tags: java, string

I am working on some logic . But I am unable to find it i.e I have

```
String s1 = "10010001";
```

now I want get repeated greatest no.of 0s in between 1s .

For example in the above string output should be 3
ex2 : `String s2 = "10001000001";` output : `5` like this.

can any one help me out how to resolve this.
I tried like this,

```
String s1 = "10010001";
for (int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++) {

    //System.out.println(s1.charAt(i));
    if (s1.charAt(i) == '1') {

        System.out.println(s1.charAt(i));
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: @Shashwat I tried like this String s1 = "10010001";
  
  for(int i=0;i<s1.length();i++){
   
   //System.out.println(s1.charAt(i));
    
   if(s1.charAt(i)=='1'){
    
    System.out.println(s1.charAt(i));    
   }
  }

Comment: Split by `1+` and check whats the largest string in the array you get as a result.

Comment: For this string "000010001" is it 4 or 3? You wrote between 1s

Comment: How do you do it "in your head"? You count them, and stop when you reach a 1, right? And you start over when you see a new 0, right. And if the new count is bigger than the maximum you got before, it becomes the new max, right? So, do the same with code.

Comment: @barbakini lets assume the input should be in between 1s only. 1000010001 , then o/p should be 4

Comment: *"I tried like this...but its not correct way I knew"* It's not **any** way. All that's doing is printing out the 1s it finds. Please review [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Assignments aren't usually arbitrary; your instructor, tutorial, or course will have covered the necessary information to make it possible for you to do this. Review your course materials, class notes, etc., and try to do the work. **If** you run into a *specific* problem, post your code and a description of the problem you're having, and people will be glad to help.

Comment: @PavanAlapati GhostCat and JB have almost done your work, there is hardly anything left for you to do. Can't you implement their Idea in code ? Do you expect someone to post written code for you  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 String s1 = "10010001000001001";
    int len = 0, preLen = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++) {
        len = 0;
        if (s1.charAt(i) == '1') {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < s1.length(); j++) {
                if (s1.charAt(j) == '0') {
                    len++;
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (preLen < len) {
                preLen = len;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Len =" + preLen);
```

Answer (score 3):

Yet another solution:

```
Arrays.stream("011111111000010001".split("1"))
    .map(String::length)
    .max(Integer::compare)
    .orElse(0);
```

Comment: it is a good answer using java 8, if you don't mind you can use my solution `String str = "1000010001";
String[] spl = str.split("1");//[, 0000, 000]
Arrays.sort(spl);//to get the max you can sort your array then get the last element
System.out.println(spl[spl.length - 1].length());` i get many down-vote for unknown reason so it can help others in future

Answer (score 0):

```
String s1 = "10010001";
int maxFoundZeros = 0;
int currentFoundZeros = 0;
for(int i=0;i<s1.length();i++){
  // if there is a 0 at current position: increase currentFoundZeros
  // if there is a 1 at current position: 
  //   if currentFoundZeros is greater than maxFoundZeros: set maxFoundZeros to currentFoundZeros.
  //   clear currentFoundZeros to start new counting with newly found 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with a **Regex**:

```
String s1 = "10010001";
// length of string having max 0's
int max = Collections.max(s1.split("0*0")).length();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char[] charArray = s1.toCharArray();
    int maxNoOfZeros = 0;
    int noOfZeros = 0;
    for(char c : charArray){
        if(c=='1'){
            if(maxNoOfZeros<noOfZeros){
                maxNoOfZeros = noOfZeros;
            }
            noOfZeros = 0;
        }else{
            noOfZeros++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Max no of zeros : "+maxNoOfZeros);
```